# Implementing a generic Comparator

Tags: beginner, typescript

I'm familiar with JS, however just today started TypeScript. Experimenting with the type system and generics, I thought to implement a comparator yielding 3 distinct results and created the following:

```
export function compare<T>(s1: T, s2: T): number {
    let equal = 0;
    let greater = 1;
    let lesser = -1

    // Special cases: consider "undefined" and "null" to be less than defined
    if (nullOrUndefined(s1) && nullOrUndefined(s2)) {
        return equal;
    } else if (nullOrUndefined(s1) ^ nullOrUndefined(s2)) {
        return nullOrUndefined(s2) ? greater : lesser;
    }

    // Ignore case for strings
    if (typeof s1 === 'string') {
        s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
        s2 = s2.toLowerCase();
    }

    // Use JS default
    return s1 === s2 ? equal : s1 > s2 ? greater : lesser;
}

export function nullOrUndefined(input: any): boolean {
    return input === undefined || input === null;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Are the variables necessary? I keep going back and forth on this / wonder if it aids clarity in any way. Sometimes feel like it's intuitive, but I even wonder if an enumeration representing comparison results outside could be superior.
2. My first implementation used the `any` type, but it feels more appropriate to apply it this way since it should always compare like-items. This feels like a sensical assumption, but would `any` prove more handy and 'generic' in *any* case?
3. For any unfamiliar with JS weirdness, see this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Comment: `return input === undefined || input === null` is not TS idiomatic, I believe. `return input == null` would achieve same result.

Comment: I hesitate to write a real answer, because I'm not sure what is the contract of this function. How exactly should it work on array types (`T[]`), complex object types, and so on. Another thing is the assumption of `always compare like-items` is only appropriate under some special limitations, namely that there will be no _TS_ class hierarchies involved into the equation. Take a look at [this scenario](https://gist.github.com/another-guy/e459cea9430d66519b08769e6a2e639d). I think your question is specific, but it should be either improved or closed since code does not do what it claims to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, because this function can be simplified, I don't believe the variables are necessary. Since you are using Typescript, an `enum` would fit well here, but I believe even this is unnecessary. The results of a compare function are well standardized.

```ts
enum Result {
  equal = 0,
  greater = 1,
  lesser = -1
}
```

You are correct that it is more appropriate to apply the function with generics. If somewhere you *need* the flexibility that `any` provides, you can simply call the function with `compare<any>(a, b)` to override the type. I personally have found that `any` is only useful when first converting a project and will avoid it like the plague if at all possible.

Now, a few comments about the function itself.

1. I'm not sure how you are compiling this, but it emits three errors in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20compare%3CT%3E%28s1%3A%20T%2C%20s2%3A%20T%29%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20equal%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20greater%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20lesser%20%3D%20-1%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Special%20cases%3A%20consider%20%22undefined%22%20and%20%22null%22%20to%20be%20less%20than%20defined%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28nullOrUndefined%28s1%29%20%26%26%20nullOrUndefined%28s2%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20equal%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20%28nullOrUndefined%28s1%29%20%5E%20nullOrUndefined%28s2%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20nullOrUndefined%28s2%29%20%3F%20greater%20%3A%20lesser%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ignore%20case%20for%20strings%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28typeof%20s1%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string'%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20s1%20%3D%20s1.toLowerCase%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20s2%20%3D%20s2.toLowerCase%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Use%20JS%20default%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20s1%20%3D%3D%3D%20s2%20%3F%20equal%20%3A%20s1%20%3E%20s2%20%3F%20greater%20%3A%20lesser%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20nullOrUndefined%28input%3A%20any%29%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20input%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%7C%7C%20input%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D).

   1. `nullOrUndefined(s1) ^ nullOrUndefined(s2)` - The '^' operator is not allowed for boolean types. Consider using '!==' instead.
   2. `s1 = s1.toLowerCase();`- Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
   3. `s2 = s2.toLowerCase();` - Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'T'.
2. You will have problems if you try to use this function with the built in `Array.prototype.sort` function because `undefined` results in the array being treated as a sparse array. [See the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort).
3. To ignore string case, it would be better to use [`String.prototype.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Here is how I would implement this function. I purposely use `==` instead of `===` for comparing `null` as it also catches `undefined`.

```
function compare<T>(a: T, b: T): number {
    if (a == b) return 0;
    if (a == null) return -1;
    if (b == null) return 1;

    // To appease the type system, check both
    // I think it might be a bug that this is required
    if (typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string') {
        return a.localeCompare(b, 'standard', { sensitivity: 'case'});
    }

    return b > a ? -1 : 1;
}
```